# while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) is not working

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, fetch, mysql-num-rows

What i try to do is check the user's Id by verifying in a cookie (called "identification").

thats my code:

```
if(!$noCookie) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `". TABLE_PREFIX ."_logged` WHERE `logged_cookie` = '". $usersCookie ."' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0) {
    echo 'yes cookie';

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    print_r($row);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $usersId = $row["logged_user_id"];
    }
} else {
    echo 'no cookie';
}
}
```

What happends is that if the user's cookie is the same one like in the table,
it will return the user's id.

so thats what im trying to do, the IF says "yes cookie", but inside the while it doesnt do anything!
and its not giving me an error.

Comment: Please read the manual entry for `mysql_fetch_array` to better understand what that function does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php - and keep in mind: once a row fetched, it hops on the next one or returns false if there are no more rows.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no rows, there's nothing to be fetched.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0) {
```

Should this be `> 0`?

Answer (score 1):

You only ran `mysql_fetch_array` when `mysql_num_rows($query)` evaluated to 0 or less; i.e. *there are no rows*.

Perhaps you meant:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) { // <-----
    echo 'yes cookie';

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    // ...
}
else {
    echo 'no cookie';
}
```

---

Also note that you're running `mysql_fetch_array` in two different places, which is normally not right. Your `while` loop will not include the first result row, because you already did `mysql_fetch_array` once before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!$noCookie) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `". TABLE_PREFIX ."_logged` WHERE `logged_cookie` = '". $usersCookie ."' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo 'yes cookie';

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());   
    foreach ($row as $r)
       echo $r["logged_user_id"];
} else {
    echo 'no cookie';
}
}
```